# .htaccess RewriteRule working in some cases and not others

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This part of my .htaccess file directs requests for /x or /x/ to x.php (for just the 6 pages listed below). However, requests for /links and /contact (without the ending slash) are showing a 404 page. The other pages redirect correctly with or without the ending slash. What could be causing those two instances to not work like the others?

```
RewriteRule ^art/$ art.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^design/$ design.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^projects/$ projects.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^teaching/$ teaching.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^links/$ links.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I was using that previously and it worked, but it seemed to cause loops.

Comment: try adding an `[R]` flag to make sure that redirect is correct. And make sure those two files physically EXIST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess, that for `art`, `design`, `projects` and `teaching`, you have corresponding directories. This causes a redirect from `/art` to `/art/` and then your RewriteRule can trigger.

I would make the trailing slash optional with

```
RewriteRule ^art/?$ art.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^design/?$ design.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^projects/?$ projects.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^teaching/?$ teaching.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^links/?$ links.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [QSA,L]
```

Then the rules trigger with *and* without a trailing slash.

Comment: This is exactly it. Why didn't I think of that? I was previously using the code you posted, but it occasionally caused loops, so I switched to this new code. I've fixed the problem by creating two empty folders. Thanks!